# ECONNREFUSED 3306 in Node.js connect to MySQL Container using Docker-Compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I had went through many answers related with the same title on internet, unfortunately none of it resolve my problem

I have a docker file consist of 4 service includes 2 frontend, 1 API and a mysql database.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    container_name: miAPI
    build: ./MI_Assessment_Back_end
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE 
    volumes:
      - ./database/mia.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      - ./database/mia:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" 
    restart: always 
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mia
      MYSQL_USER: express
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql

  app:
    depends_on:
      - api
    build: ./miassessment_app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  fms:
    depends_on:
      - api
    build: ./miassessment_fms
    ports:
      - 4000:4000

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
```

I have an env file inside every project folder except for database so I am hardcoding environment varible for mysql in docker-compose file.

My API in node.js is showing the error

> ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

My API env file looks like this

```properties
port=8080
user=express
password=password
database=mia
db_port=3306
host=localhost
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong.

I tried
Change the ports of docker and mysql expose along with api env file. Nothing worked.

I am expecting to see a status DB Connected without any errors to fetch data through my API

Comment: Change your database setup to use the Compose service name `mysql` of the other container, and double-check that you're using the standard MySQL port 3306.  Delete especially the Compose `links:` option, but also `expose:` and `container_name:`, all are unnecessary and `links:` has occasionally caused connectivity problems.

Comment: I tried that, still I am having the same issue and MySQL is getting restarted always

Comment: Remove the `MYSQL_HOST` env var and pay attention to the notes in [the documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql#environment-variables)... _"variables like `MYSQL_HOST`, which is known to cause issues when used with this image"_